# Spring session jdbc with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, session, spring-boot, jdbc

I've got a springboot application and I'm trying to configure it to use spring jdbc session with a postgresql database. It works but:

On application startup, it creates automatically tables and indexes in public schema, what is wrong. I've got already created both spring_session and spring_session_attributes and I need it to use them. So:

- How can I make spring session to use a specific schema. I've tryed to setting it by configuring `spring.datasource.url` property as follows but it didn't work. 
  `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9999/db_name?currentSchema=<schema_name>`
- How can I configure spring session to NOT to create tables but use those that I've already create For instance `my_schema.spring_session`

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, it works. You should create the database and schema in advance.
You should not use *@EnableJdbcHttpSession* annotation in Spring Boot to enable the autoconfiguration.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<db_name>?currentSchema=<schema_name>
    username: test
    password: test
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  session:
    store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
```